# Unterminated string constant MVC onclick

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a HomeController and this controller includes Login Action.
I want to go that Action when I click the button but there is an error, unterminated string constant.

How can I fix it?

```
 <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Login","Home")'">LOGIN</a>
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using `.onclick` - its already a link just set the `href` attribute, or better use `@Html.ActionLink("LOGIN", "Login", "Home", null, new { @class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to set value to `location.href` using javascript in this case as this is an anchor tag and as long as you have a valid `href` property value, it will be redirected to that on clicking on the link (unless you are overriding the click behavior and doing something (preventing the default behavior) using javascript.

You should be doing

```
 <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" href="@Url.Action("Login","Home")">LOGIN</a>
```

Or using the `Html.ActionLink` [Html helper method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) to generate the anchor tag

```
@Html.ActionLink("Login", "Login", "Home", null ,
                                     new {@class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"})
```